# Non-linear editing with GNonLin/gnlcomposition

Tags: gstreamer, video-processing

I would like to play in sequence multiple video and after apply some effects. I suppose  that `gnlcomposition` can help me.

Official `gnlcomposition`  [documentation](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gnonlin/html/GnlComposition.html) is really minimal. So I started testing some gnlcomposition scripts based on `gst-launch` that I googled around.

If I run:

```
>gst-launch gnlcomposition (^
 gnlfilesource name="s1" location="file:///C:/p/test/a.mp4" ^
 start=0 duration=240 media-start=0 media-duration=240 ^
 gnlfilesource name="s2" location="file:///C:/p/test/b.mp4" ^
 start=0 duration=240 media-start=0 media-duration=240 ^
 ) ! queue ! videorate ! progressreport name="Merging " ! ^
 ffmpegcolorspace ! ffenc_mpeg4 ! ffmux_mp4 ! ^
 filesink location="C:/p/test/c.mp4"
```

I get:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
0:00:00.303017000  4052   0204B3E8 ERROR                 
ffmpeg .:0:: Tag mp4v/0x7634706d incompatible with output codec id '13'
Merging  (00:00:00): 0 seconds
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/ffmux_mp4:ffmux_mp40: 
Could not configure supporting library.
0:00:00.305017000 Additional debug info:
..\..\..\..\..\Source\gst-ffmpeg\ext\ffmpeg\gstffmpegmux.c(654): 
gst_ffmpegmux_collected (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/ffmux_mp4:ffmux_mp40:
Failed to write file header - check codec settings
4052 ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
0204B3E8 Setting pipeline to NULL ...
ERROR    ffmpeg .:0:: Tag mp4v/0x7634706d incompatible with output codec id '13'
Freeing pipeline ...
```

I am using the [Ossbuild](http://code.google.com/p/ossbuild/) Win64 binaries:
`GStreamer-WinBuilds-GPL-x86-Beta04-0.10.7.msi`

Can you help and/or give reference to proper documentations?